# Is it possible to add a second custom ActionBar?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I tried to add a second `ActionBar` but that didn't work as expected. The action bar appeared at the top of the frame above everything else and not where I wanted it to go.

All I want to do is add another section under the `ActionBar` so I can display some icons and text.

I started with a `Label` as a test but it wouldn't even display on the page.

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" @tap="onDrawerButtonTap"></NavigationButton>

    <ActionItem icon="res://navigation/menu"
                android:visibility="collapsed"
                @tap="onDrawerButtonTap"
                ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>

    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Tasks"></Label>

    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="16" ios.position="right"
                android.systemIcon="ic_menu_add" android.position="popup"
                text="Add" class="add-task"
                @tap="addTodo">
    </ActionItem>
    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="16" ios.position="right"
                 android.position="popup"
                text="Sort" class="sort-tasks"
                @tap="sortTodos">
    </ActionItem>
    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="16" ios.position="right"
                icon="res://menu" android.position="popup"
                text="Delete" class="delete-task">
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>

<Label text="Label" class="item" />

<GridLayout class="page-content">
    <ListView for="(task, index) in todosFiltered" key="task.id" @itemTap="onLabelTap" row="0">
        <v-template>
            <GridLayout columns="auto,*">
                <!--<CheckBox :text="task.title" :checked="task.completed" @checkedChange="onCheckChange($event, task, index)" col="0" />-->
                <Label :text="task.title" class="item" :class="{ completed : task.completed}" col="0" row="0" />
            </GridLayout>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: You could use 2 frames, one ActionBar at top frame another in the frame below. Otherwise simply create one with your own custom layout.

Comment: using `<Frame>` didn't work. As for a custom layout, I tried them, none of them worked. I tried Stacked, Flex and Docked.

Comment: First of all, you can have only one element at root level, that's said you can't have both Label and GridLayout at same level. More than one element should be always wrapped inside a layout. Please share a Playground sample if you are still unable to tackle it, I might able to take a quick look.

Comment: I think that fixed it. I had to wrap both of them in a `StackLayout` and it is now displaying as you'd expect. And I managed to create a pseudo-ActionBar using another nested `GridLayout`

Comment: @Manoj please post your solution so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use multiple ActionBar, you should have multiple frames. So each page at each frame can have a ActionBar.

If you don't want to complicate with multiple frames, you may use custom layout. Looking at your sample code, you can have only one element at root level, that's said you can't have both **Label** and **GridLayout** at same level. ***More than one element should be always wrapped inside a layout.***

Answer (score 0):

use Gradient and GridLayout for custom action bar

```html
<FlexboxLayout justifyContent="center" class="page">
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <StackLayout>
        <Gradient direction="to right">
          <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto, *" columns="50, 80, *">
            <Label row="0" col="0" flexGrow="1" class="fas m-t-25 m-l-15" style="font-size: 20px; color: #fff;" text="&#xf060;"
              (tap)="goBack()"></Label>
          </GridLayout>
        </Gradient>
      </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </FlexboxLayout>
```